# Retrieve data from service in other template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, web

I have a service

```
.factory('myService', function($http, $q) {

var deffered = $q.defer();
var data = [];  
var myService = {};

myService.async = function() {
$http.get('/*some json file from http adress*/')
.success(function (d) {
    data = d;
    deffered.resolve();
});
    return deffered.promise;
};
myService.data = function() { return data; };

return myService;
});
```

and controller (for user state mainly)

```
.controller('Ctrl', function( myService, $scope) {
    myService.async().then(function() {
        $scope.dataarray = myService.data();
    });
});
```

ui-router

```
  .state('profile', {
    url: '/user/:login',
    templateUrl: 'userprofile.html', 
    controller: 'Ctrl',      
  })
```

and in user.html(the parent state of profile) I used (after ng-repeat user in dataarray )

```
ui-sref="profile({ login: user.login})
```

to go to my template for specific user page called userprofile.html

The final question is how get in userprofile.html whole date from json file connected to the **specified** user.login that I send through ui-sref to display eg. his name, avatar etc. from one json data entry.
I think I have to use a some sort of new controller to use in profile state.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: `myService` is recovering the user right?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud not one but all entries from json file from api.github.com/users

Comment: so you are navigating to different state and want to pass some data to be available there, right? just pass it through params as you already do with `login: user.login`